# How to mount a UDF file as a volume in Win 7, 8, or 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, mount, udf

I have a 2GB file from a vendor that I downloaded. There's no built-in support in Windows to mount the file as a virtual disk. I have tried several tools but none support this file format:

- Alcohol 120%
- DVDFab
- Virtual CloneDrive
- MagicISO
- 4Media ISO Burner

Is there some tool to mount this file or perhaps some other way to do it in Windows?

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/udf-file-2622842

Answer (score 0):

UDF (Universal Disk FOrmat) files are described by [DiskInternals](http://www.diskinternals.com/glossary/udf.html) as a substitute for ISO. DiskInternals has a a [commercial tool](https://www.diskinternals.com/cd-dvd-recovery/) to mount them, but [Adaptec offers a (free?) tool to read UDF-format drives](http://download.cnet.com/Adaptec-UDF-Reader-Driver/3000-2100_4-10021086.html), as does [Roxio](http://www.roxio.com/enu/support/udf/software_updates.html).

Comment: It's a file, so the Adaptec tool will not work. Roxio and the DiskInternals tools look promising. However, I finally found a free one that will work - WinCDEmu http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found one that worked -

[WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/)

This is the only one that worked for me on a Win 7 box.